# how do i move from the first page, to another page by using items from the first page

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, bloc

[image]

How do i move from the first page to another page by using items from the first page?

I am using pageview on the page menu, can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

So basically you can create a variable that contains the value on your first page and while you add your pages in any list you can simply pass that value like

```
int test=0
  final List<Widget> _list = [];
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _list.addAll(
        const [DashboardScreen(test), WishListScreen(),   CartScreen(), ProfileScreen()]);
  }
```

And other side in dashboardscreen

```
  final int test;
  const DashboardScreen(this.test, {Key? key}) : super(key: key);
```

if your page is statful widget then in build file you can simple use **widget.test**
or if you have stateless widget you can directly use test variable

Comment: I still don't understand, can you explain in detail? @akshay-gupta

Comment: Can you please share me your some code that how you arrived this problem?

Comment: yes sure, how can i share it? here?

Comment: Simply copy your code file where you arrived this problem after that edit your question with code. for more you can follow the guidelines here
https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I have several blocks to adjust page movement, menupage which adjusts page displacement and home menu or page 1 which has an item which when clicked it moves to page 2 @akshay-gupta

Comment: Yes understand but need a block of code to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use page controller

// through the page controller you can do using animateToPage or _pageController.jumpToPage(0). here 0 is page index

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

const Color darkBlue = Color.fromARGB(255, 18, 32, 47);

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData.dark().copyWith(
        scaffoldBackgroundColor: darkBlue,
      ),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: MyPageView(),
    );
  }
}

class MyPageView extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyPageView({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyPageView> createState() => _MyPageViewState();
}

class _MyPageViewState extends State<MyPageView> {
  final PageController _pageController = PageController();

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _pageController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: PageView(
          controller: _pageController,
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              color: Colors.red,
              child: Center(
                child: ElevatedButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    if (_pageController.hasClients) {
                      
                      _pageController.animateToPage(
                        1,
                        duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 400),
                        curve: Curves.easeInOut,
                      );
                      
                      // you can use animateToPage or _pageController.jumpToPage(0). here 0 is page index
                    }
                  },
                  child: const Text('Next'),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Container(
              color: Colors.blue,
              child: Center(
                child: ElevatedButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    if (_pageController.hasClients) {
                      _pageController.animateToPage(
                        0,
                        duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 400),
                        curve: Curves.easeInOut,
                      );
                    }
                  },
                  child: const Text('Previous'),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I have already solved this problem, my question is how the item on page 1 or home or index 0, can move to the menu page 2 @krbutani

Comment: Means you need to send data from one page to another?